# How can I make it pssible for users to login and add their products?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, plugin, form, e-commerce

I want to build a form for the users of my website to let them easily add their products in frontend page under the name of their shop.

To this end, which plug-in,  component, or extension completely match my requirements and are free?

Thank you so much guys in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a "multi vendor" solution.

[HikaMarket](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/hikamarket) can do this but it's not free.

It looks like [Sellacious](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/shopping-cart/sellacious/) is free and does multi-vendor.

Comment: Adding here: quick2cart is multi-vendor, and virtuemart can be made multivendor with plugins. Virtuemart is free, but both the multivendor plugin and quick2cart are commercial.